# Definition of the pullback vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, pullback

I've some problems with the definition of the pullback vector bundle.
Say $F : M \rightarrow N$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function between differential varieties, and $\pi : E \rightarrow N$ a vector bundle over $N$.
We define $F^*E$, the pullback vector bundle of $E$, by saying:

1. $(F^*E)_p = E_{F(p)}$ be the fiber over $p \in M$
2. $F^*E = \bigsqcup_p \, (F^*E)_p$
3. $\tilde{\pi} : F^*E \rightarrow M$, with $\tilde{\pi} = F^*(\pi) = \pi \circ F$

With this definitions $\tilde{\pi}: F^*E \rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle

Now, the problem is in the definition of $\tilde{\pi}$. I expect that:

$$\tilde{\pi}(F^*E)_p = p$$
but
$$\tilde{\pi}(F^*E)_p = \tilde{\pi} E_{F(p)} = \pi \circ F(E_{F(p)}) \neq p = F^{-1} \circ \pi (E_{F(p)})$$
Where i go wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What is $\pi \circ F(E_{F(p)})$? Neither $\pi\circ F$ nor $F(E_{F(p)})$ make sense to me.

Comment: I agree, but it follow from the definition of $\tilde{\pi} = F^*(\pi)$. By what i know, $f^*(g) = g \circ f$, where $f^*$ is the pullback of $f$.

Comment: Where did you find this definition as 3. looks completely messed up? I suggest you first check up in books on category theory the construction of a pullback of sets, as the other parts of your `input' seem not relevant to the problem you are posing.

Comment: Take $F^*(E) := \{(p,e)\in M\times E\ |\ F(p) =\pi(e)\}$ and define $\tilde{\pi}(p,e)=p$. This is a definition of the pull-back bundle which works for many other contexts.

Comment: Thanks! This seems a better definition, also from a working viewpoint

Comment: It should also be pointed out that the `definition' you gave does not give a topology on $F^*(E)$. As I said before, look at the definition of pullback of sets first. After that look at pullback of spaces as that disjoint union is deceptive. It is rather a subset of the product... which solves the problem of the topology.